# Where are the twig view files generated by Symfony's generate:crud command?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, crud

I have used Symfony's command line tool to generate CRUD functionality for an entity in my application.

According to the documentation the twig view files are based on templates within the Sensio Generator bundle.

Are a separate set of files are generated exclusively for that particular entity whenever the 'doctrine:generate:crud' command is run?

**OR**

No twig files are generated, all entities that have CRUD functionality generated using the command line tool use the twig template files in the Sensio Generator bundle.

If the former is correct, can anyone tell me the directory for these twig files pls?

I hope my question makes sense. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All views created from the `doctrine:generate:crud` command will be generated in the following path :

```
app/Resources/views/entityName/
```

The rule is simple, a folder named like the Entity is created in the `app/Resources/views` directory, and all views of the CRUD are generated into.

Comment: Side note Sid, check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html#overriding-skeleton-templates

Comment: Thank you, I tried to find it in the command documentation, it was here.